# Does the Android NDK support most UNIX system calls?

Tags: c, unix, android-ndk, system-calls

I'm attempting to fix and then port an old project written in C to run on Android. This project uses system calls, such as stat(file, inode) and system(command).

Are these features fully supported in the Android NDK? Or would I be better off rewriting the whole project in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the most important POSIX functions not available in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111640/what-are-the-most-important-posix-functions-not-available-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use system calls and libc functions with Android NDK.

- https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/SYSCALLS.TXT
- system() - https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/include/stdlib.h#L99
- https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/docs/OVERVIEW.TXT
- http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/