# How to run a C program in adb shell?

Tags: android, c, adb

So `adb shell` gives one a linux terminal into an android phone, when it is connected to a computer. One can run all the standard linux commands like `ls` and `cat` inside the android phone, and explore the android filesystem using the `adb shell`.

Now I wonder, is it possible to use a C/C++ compiler such as `clang` or `gcc` to compile and execute a C/C++ program in the android phone, as on linux? I am not talking about android app development here, I mean a linux command line C/C++ program for android. Also, can I use the C standard library and linux system calls such as `fork()`, `exec()`, `kill()`, and working with file descriptors, in the android `adb shell`, just as I would do it on linux?

Comment: Related: [Running own executable on Android shell](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/45554/3573) and [How to build an executable for Android shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35231168/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Can you give me any information about possibility to run c/c++ linux system calls in android using these methods you linked here?

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for: [Does the Android NDK support most UNIX system calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10626034/295004). Realize that if you want a linux user-like environment to run on the phone, see: [Termux](https://termux.com/) *Usual disclaimer that software recommendations are off-topic here*

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thank you sir. I believe that you answered my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can . For that you need copy your compiler exe's to android file system. From there you can easily call. Same time make sure that all pre-builed libs in android PATH folder.